# How to get process.env on onRenderBody

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm using onRenderBody in my Gatsby project to load this html:

I need to get the keys, like `GATSBY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID`, from process.env.
I tried to use `process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID` directly, but this still not working.

```
const React = require('react');

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPreBodyComponents }) => {
  setPreBodyComponents(
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=%GATSBY_GOOGLE_ADS_TRACKING_ID%"></script>,
    <script
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

      gtag('config', 'GATSBY_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID', {
        'optimize_id': 'GATSBY_GOOGLE_OPTIMIZE_TRACKING_ID'
      });

      gtag('config', 'GATSBY_GOOGLE_ADS_TRACKING_ID')

    `,
      }}
    />
  );
```

};

Does anyone know how I can get these parameters from process.env?

Thanks

Comment: If you are using create react app script, the environmental variables get the prefix REACT_APP_  so REACT_APP_GATSBY_GOOGE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING_ID. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: Just to confirm. Are you setting a .env.development and .env.production in the root of your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby configures webpack to replace references to `process.env.GATSBY_FOO`  with their values at build time. This uses static analysis so things like destructuring will fail, so typically I use direct references, like this:

```
exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPreBodyComponents }) => {
  const googleId = process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ID

  setPreBodyComponents([
    <script key="example" src={`https://example.com/id/${googleId}`} />
  ])
}
```

This should also work fine if you do away with the extra local variable and references `process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_ID` directly in the backtick-delimited string.

Answer (score 0):

Process.env is a node thing, are you in the node environment? If you're using a bundler like webpack you'll need to inject it yourself. Be careful though! Sending environment variables to the frontend can be insecure depending on your use case. Here's how I did it in my webpack.config

```
plugins: [
  ...,
  new webpack.DefinePlugin(
    Object.entries(process.env).map(
      ([k, v]) => ([`env.${k}`, `"${v}"` ])
    ).filter(
      ([k]) => !k.includes('SECRET') && !k.includes('PASSWORD')
    ).reduce(
      (acc, [envVarKey, envVarVal]) => {
        acc[envVarKey] = envVarVal; return acc;
      },
      {}
    )
  ),
  ...
]
```

That code puts your environment vars into a global called 'env' on the frontend. Use like:

```
if (env.APP_ENV === 'development') console.dir('dev is in env!')
```